# Create alert when site speed is slow on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Tags: pagespeed-insights, opsgenie

is it possible to create alerts when your website's google site speed is below the threshold?

I couldn't anything in the google docs and it suggested at the bottom to post question in stackoverflow.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about

Comment: Not an expert here, but you might be able to create a Google Analytics Custom alert when your website goes below a certain score. Also in order to do this, you need to integrate GA speed tracking.

Comment: There is a tool specifically tailored to monitor google pagespeed insights scores: https://pagespeedplus.com.